# Order of Pcollection while doing flatten in beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a use case where I need to read content of a file and extract data from database with merging them together.

Example

File content:

```
"This is an example text from a file"
```

Table content:

```
LOADDATE|20221001
EXTRACTDATE|20221001
COUNT|10
```

My output should look like

```
This is an example text from a file
LOADDATE|20221001
EXTRACTDATE|20221001
COUNT|10
```

I have taken 2 PCollection and use flatten to combine them.

The issue is I am not getting the sequence correct always. Sometimes I get the table extract before the text file content.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: I would need you to share more information about your use case to be able to help you forward. Specifically: How do you join the data together? Just as it comes? Is there a key you use to join your data? What is your current code? Is this Java, Go or Python?

Comment: The requirement was to build an extraction framework in apache beam using dataflow. The first part would extract the data from different source like spanner or a bigquery table and write to a text file. The second part is to obtain a rowcount of this extract and write as a summary file and this would also have some other information which can be obtained from another query. So the union of rowcount and the second query's output need to be done in same dataflow pipeline. I could design a simple python code in airflow to run but the architecture team doesn't want any data processing to run there

Answer (score 0):

The elements in a `PCollection` are unordered. This is fundamental: the reason you can do parallel processing is the lack of order. Forcing order prevents parallel processing.

If you have enough data that you need a big data processing framework like Beam, then perhaps you want to actually do this operation many millions of times in parallel for different files and tables. In that case, the actually concatenation of the file content and the table content would not happen by flattening `PCollections` but by processing of the individual files.

Comment: Hi Kenn, could you please give me some more idea how to achieve this in dataflow i.e. processing of the files as you have mentioned.